# Undefined behaviour seems to be contradicting with operator precedence rule in C

Tags: c

Consider the following line of code.

```
int i = 2;
i = i++
```

The second line of code has been identified as undefined. I know this question has been asked before several times and example being [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior-in-c).

But nowhere could I see the issue of operator precedence being addressed in this issue. It has been clearly mentioned that postfix operator precedes assignment operator.

```
i = (i++)
```

So clearly i++ will be evaluated first and this value of i is the assigned to i again.

This looks like this particular undefined behavior is contradicting the precedence rule.

Similar to this is the code:

```
int i = 2;
i++ * i++;
```

Here according to operator precedence the code can be written as

```
int i =2;
(i++) * (i++)
```

Now we do not know whether the (i++) in LHS or RHS of '*' operator is going to be evaluated first. But either way it is going produce the same result. So how is it undefined?

If we write say:

```
int p;
p = f1() + f2()
```

where f1() and f2() are defined functions then obviously it's clear we can't decide whether f1() or f2() is going to be evaluated first as precedence rules does not specify this. But a confusion like this does not seem to arise in the current problem.

Please explain.

I do not understand why this question got a negative vote. I needed a clarity between operator precedence and UB and I have seen no other question addressing it.

Comment: `i++` will be evaluated and value will be returned. The UB is arising not from this but from the fact you can't know *when* the value of `i` is going to be *updated* as a result of this operation.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Why cannot we be sure about it? i++ update the value of i when called independently. Why not update when called in an expression?

Comment: Because C is not working this way. The side effect of `i++` is guaranteed to be carried out only after a sequence point, but not guaranteed *not* to be carried out before. In Java it will be like you describe (AFAIK)

Comment: does `i` get set to `i` and then the side-effect `i++` takes place, or does the side-effect happen first only for `i` to be set to the value of what `i` was before the side-effect?

Comment: Please don't add extra questions after receiving two comprehensive answers.

Comment: @EugeneSh. So as you said the side effect of i++ which is incrementing the value of i is guaranteed to be carried out after a sequence point and the nearest sequence point is the end of the expression here. So naturally it's only gonna be guaranteed that i will be incremented after the end of expression but may or may not get incremented in between and this is the root cause of the UB here. Am I right?

Comment: Yes.I think the answers are addressing it.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is in section 6.5 on Expressions, paragraph 3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax.
>   **Except as specified later, side effects and value computations of
>   subexpressions are unsequenced.**

This means that the side effect of incrementing (or decrementing) via the `++` or `--` operators doesn't necessarily happen immediately when the operator is encountered.  The only guarantee is that it happens before the next sequence point.

In the case of `i = i++;`, there is no sequence point in the evaluation of the operands of `=` nor in the evaluation of postfix `++`.  So an implementation is free to perform assigning the current value of `i` to itself and the side effect of incrementing of `i` in any order.  So `i` could potentially be either 2 or 3 in your example.

This goes back to paragraph 2:

> If  a  side  effect  on  a  scalar  object  is  unsequenced  relative 
>   to either  a  different  side  effect on  the  same  scalar  object 
>   or  a  value  computation  using  the  value  of  the  same  scalar
>   object,  the  behavior  is  undefined.

Since `i = i++` attempts to update `i` more than once without a sequence point, it invokes undefined behavior.  The result could be 2 or 3, or something else might happen as a result of optimizations for example.

The reason that this is *not* undefined:

```
int p;
p = f1() + f2()
```

Is because a variable is not being updated more than once in a sequence point.  It *could* however be unspecified behavior if both `f1` and `f2` update the same global variables, since the evaluation order is unspecified.

Comment: You said that the evaluation of operands of '=' has no sequence point. But isn't there an implicit sequence point in evaluation of operands of '=' ? The LHS of '=' operator is guaranteed to be an l-value. If we write say int a = f(), the operands are a and f(). Now isn't it guaranteed here that f() will be evaluated first? Can you cite an example where the LHS of the assignment operator could be evaluated first leading to UB?

Comment: @TARS You're correct that the right hand side of an assignment must be evaluated before being assigned to the left side.  However, the left side needs to be evaluated as well.  For example if `a` is an array, then `a[f()]` is an lvalue.  That needs to be evaluated before it can be assigned to.  So in an expression like `a[f()] = g();` whether `f` or `g` is run first is unspecified.

Comment: @TARS And that still doesn't touch on side effects such as those caused by `++` or `--`.

Comment: I wish to get one more point clear. Say we consider the example you gave here,  **a[f()] = g()**. Let us say g() gets evaluated first and suppose g() modifies some global variable **int a** and finally it returns some other variable **int c**. Now we are guaranteed that all the body of the function will be done before it returns the final value. In general all the side effects will be updated before the value is returned. So with the same logic here why is it that the value is returned by i++ but the side effect of incrementing the value i may not be done?

Comment: @TARS Calling a function creates a sequence point.  Using `++` does not.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using

```
i = i++
```

is that the order in which the address of `i` is accessed to read and write is not specified. As a consequence, at the end of that line, the value of `i` could be `3` or `2`.

When will it be `3`?

1. Evaluate the RHS - `2`
2. Assign it to the LHS. `i` is now `2`.
3. Increment `i`. `i` is now `3`.

When will it be `2`?

1. Evaluate the RHS - `2`
2. Increment `i`. `i` is now `3`.
3. Assign the result of evaluating the RHS to the LHS. `i` is now `2`.

Of course, if there is a race condition, we don't know what's going to happen.

Answer (score 1):

> But nowhere could I see the issue of operator precedence being addressed in this issue.

Operator precedence only affects how expressions are *parsed* (which operands are grouped with which operators) - it has no effect on how expressions are *evaluated*.  Operator precedence says that `a * b + c` should be parsed as `(a * b) + c`, but it *doesn't* say that either `a` or `b` *must* be evaluated before `c`.

> Now we do not know whether the (i++) in LHS or RHS of '*' operator is going to be evaluated first. But either way it is going produce the same result. So how is it undefined?

Because the side effect of the `++` operator does not have to be applied immediately after evaluation.  Side effects may be deferred until the next sequence point, or they may applied before other operations, or sprinkled throughout.  So if `i` is 2, then `i++ * i++` may be evaluated as `2 * 2`, or `2 * 3`, or `3 * 2`, or `2 * 4`, or `4 * 4`, or *something else entirely*.

Comment: How can the expression give 2*4 or 4*4 ? In any case the value returned by the i++ on the right side of * will always be 2 if i = 2 right ?

Comment: @TARS:  No, there is no such guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

OPERATOR PRECEDENCE DOES **NOT** RESOLVE UNDEFINED EXPRESSION ISSUES.

Sorry for shouting, but people ask about this *all the time*.  I'm afraid I have to say your research on this question must not have been very thorough, if you didn't see this aspect being discussed.

See for example [this essay](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/readings/precvsooe.960725.html).

The expression `i = i++` tries to assign to object `i` twice.  It's therefore undefined.  Period.  Precedence doesn't save you.

Comment: I didn't have time to run through research papers and I only looked in stack overflow for this question and I couldn't find any article which differentiates it.
Also I did not expect the rules to change just because I asked about it. Just a process of learning is all.